# PostgreSQL: Error 42P01 when editing a description on column

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to edit a description on columns (or tables) on PostgreSQL, but when I try to save I get the error message:

> Error 42P01: relation "table_name" does not exist.

Is  there any solution for that? Or any other way I can write and save descriptions for the columns and tables?

Comment: What is the command that you use to edit the description of the columns? What client are you using (psql, pgAdmin III, other)? Which version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Does your command actually have "table_name" in it and not the actual name of the table you want to edit?

Comment: I'm not writing a command - i'm right-clicking the table name (or column name) at the Object Browser, than pressing "Edit Comment". A new window opens and when i'm pressing the save button I get the error message. I don't know what client I am using - how do i check it?